# Synchronize user profile with Google profile using passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I’m using passport (and passport-google-oauth) to auth a user to my web application. When the user logs in, I insert its metadata in my database (name, email, picture, access token & refresh token). But if this user updates their Google profile (e.g changes their name), then my app still has the old data. Should I update my db each time they log in? And then again, should I update it periodically anyway? If so, what is the recommended frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to all of your question is "it depends".

**1) Should I update my db each time they log in?**

It depends.

- Why are you saving it at all?
- How expensive is it to save the data?  If cheap, what's the debate?

**2) Should I update it periodically anyway?**

It depends.

The answers to the two questions, above, will be relevant.  But also...

- Are you using the data when they aren't logged in?  If so, what is the cost if the data is wrong?
- How would you determine what "periodically" means?
- How do you benefit by *not* saving every time?
- What complexity do you add to your code by working in 'do I save it or not' logic?  Is it worth it?

**3) What is the recommended frequency?**

As you can probably guess: It depends...